# Is it possible to split the values of a single row in a left dataframe that matches the key of multiple rows in the right dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I’m having a hard time expressing what I’m trying to do in a single sentence so I’ll show an example.

Here is my left dataframe (example data)

```
| Key | Data |
| ——-| --- |
| A  | 4  |
| B  | 1   |
```

Here is my right dataframe

```
| Key | Other Data |
| --- | ----       |
| A   | Monday     |
| A   | Tuesday    |
| A   | Wednesday  |
| B   | Monday     |
| A   | Thursday   |
```

I am trying to get the following output df

```
| Key  | Data |Other Data |
| ---- | ---- | —————-    |
| A    | 1    |Monday     |
| A    | 1    |Tuesday    |
| A    | 1    |Wednesday  |
| A    | 1    |Thursday   |
| B    | 1    |Monday     |
```

Because I don’t know how to go about this the way I want to, I’ve had to get a bit creative.

I tried to take the data from left to right. Then I create a copy dataframe of the right and subtract the values from the left before contacting the two tables.

That got a bit messy and didn’t work.

Please… help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.join()` method of pandas. For the right pairing of keys, I would advise to set the Key columns as indexes. This can be done within the same line:

```
df_left.set_index('Key').join(df_right.set_index('Key'))
```

Note that I'm assuming that the Data column in your desired output is 4 when  the key is A, because you didn't mention otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

By [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)ing `Data` values for groups of `Key`s:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Key')
df['Data'] = df.groupby('Key', sort=False)['Data'].transform(lambda x: x/len(x))
```

---

```
  Key  Data Other Data
0   A   1.0     Monday
1   A   1.0    Tuesday
2   A   1.0  Wednesday
3   A   1.0   Thursday
4   B   1.0     Monday
```